# different c# java result encryption

Tags: java, c#, encryption, md5

I'm stuck with this different result.
I have some code in C# like this.

```
private static UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
private static MD5CryptoServiceProvider provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

public static String MD5(String password)
{    
    String result = "";
    byte[] hash = provider.ComputeHash(encoder.GetBytes(password));
    System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in hash)
    {
        s.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower());
    }
    result = s.ToString();

    return result;
}
```

I want to do the same in java with this code.

```
public static String MD5(String password) {
  String result = "";
    try {
      MessageDigest provider = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

      byte[] hash = provider.digest(password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
      MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
      byte[] digest = m.digest(hash);
      String s = new BigInteger(1, digest).toString(16).toLowerCase();

      result = s;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LogUtil.error_Logging("Authentication", ex.getMessage());
    }   
    return result;
}
```

Which line should I change on java code?
Thanks

Comment: In addition to the answer posted, the C# code will return any leading zeros in the hash while your Java code will suppress them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are hashing your string twice.

If you want to get same result as in C# code, try this.

```
 byte[] hash = provider.digest(password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
 MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");     
 String s = new BigInteger(1, hash).toString(16).toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Worked! I didn't recognize it.
Thanks Kote